Pythonw Script is Blinking a Window
I recently try to make a simple monitoring screen with Arduino an python for computer side. Everything work fine for this exept I want to run the python code a startup without a window, so I used pythonw but a window is still apearing and another is opening and closing every 2 or 3 sec. It seem to appear only when I open with pythonw or the .pyw file extension.
here the python code:
import serial
import psutil
import GPUtil
import time
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from PIL import Image
import pystray
import threading
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='C:\\Users\\natha\\Documents\\GitHub\\arduino-serial-monitor\\log.txt', level=logging.ERROR)

try:
    run = True
    display = True


    devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
    interface = devices.Activate(
        IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
    volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))


    ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=1)

    def create_menu():
        return pystray.Menu(
            pystray.MenuItem('Quit', on_quit_callback),
            pystray.MenuItem('Reboot', on_reboot_callback),
            pystray.MenuItem(lambda text: 'Display Off' if display else 'Display On', on_display_off_callback)
        )

    def on_quit_callback(icon, item):
        global run
        icon.stop()
        ser.write('SHUTDOWN\n'.encode())
        run = False

    def on_display_off_callback(icon, item):
        global display
        display = False if display else True

    def on_reboot_callback(icon, item):
        ser.write('REBOOT\n'.encode())


    image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\natha\\Documents\\GitHub\\arduino-serial-monitor\\icon.png')
    icon = pystray.Icon('System Monitor', image, 'System Monitor', menu=create_menu())
    icon_thread = threading.Thread(target=icon.run)
    icon_thread.start()

    time.sleep(2)  # Wait for 2 seconds to give the Arduino time to get ready

    while run:
        gpus = GPUtil.getGPUs()
        gpu = gpus[0]

        cpu_usage = max(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1, percpu=True))
        memory = psutil.virtual_memory()
        memory_usage = memory.percent
        memory_usage_raw = round(memory.used / (1024 ** 3), 2)
        memory_total = round(memory.total / (1024 ** 3))
        gpu_usage = round(gpu.load * 100)
        gpu_temp = gpu.temperature

        timePrint = time.strftime('%H:%M', time.localtime())

        volumePercent = round(volume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar() * 100)

        if ser.is_open:
            if display:
                ser.write(f'INFO:CPU:{cpu_usage},MEM_RAW:{memory_usage_raw},MEM_TOTAL:{memory_total},GPU:{gpu_usage},TEMP:{gpu_temp},TIME:{timePrint},VOL:{volumePercent}\n'.encode())
            else:
                ser.write('DISPLAY_OFF\n'.encode())
        else:
            print('Serial port is not open')
        
        #if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        #    try:
        #        
        #    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        #        pass  # Ignore the error
    #
        time.sleep(0.5)  # Wait for 0.5 second before sending the next set of data
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e)

I tried to log any error but the log file was empty.

What is the [[tag:batch-file]] tag for? Your code and body text do not indicate that it is in any way important.

Here the github repo if you want the full project : https://github.com/Sarxzer/arduino-serial-monitor

I am so sorry I never used stackoverflow (to ask question) and I didn't see I was responding to you. So yes I accidently put the batch-file tag even if my question wasn't related to a batch file.

This is why I quickly removed it when I see your comment

If you want to NOT have a terminal window appear, rename your file extension to pyw instead of py. This will stop python from opening a window. Try using an IDLE like vscode. This will make the terminal window stay at the bottom of the app.

There is still a blinking window

What is the window that is blinking. Terminal or a application window. In your full code, there is an bat file which, by my knowledge, uses a terminal window. I do not have an arduino, so I can't run the code.

The bat file was just for testing, but I don't know what is this window because it blink too rapidly to see.

In your script, at the end of your code try putting h = input("Press enter to exit"). This will keep the windows open if it is a terminal.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
